# Is there a hidden joke on the spacesuits in Austin Powers: The Spy Who Shagged Me?

Tags: plot-explanation, austin-powers, the-spy-who-shagged-me

On Dr. Evil's spacesuits in *Austin Powers: The Spy Who Shagged Me* we can see a list of chemicals. The first two are obviously water and oxygen. But the final one, P^2 is not the notation for any chemical that I know of. "Pee squared" doesn't sound like something that I'd want in a spacesuit. Is it some sort of isotope? Or is it a joke or mistake?

[image: Spacesuits]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the rather lowbrow humour of the Austin Powers franchise, I'd say this is almost certainly a "pee" joke. As a matter of fact, real-life astronauts wear [special diapers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Absorbency_Garment) under their spacesuits, so they can go to the bathroom without soiling them or having to take them off.

As a side-note, P<sub>2</sub> is the chemical formula for [diphosphorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphosphorus), but I doubt that's the reference here (note the subscript '2', as opposed to the superscript '2' on their suits).

Comment: I understood it to refer to Pee and Poo, or P-squared.

Comment: Since the lettering spells out "HOOP", I wonder if it might be an obscure reference into Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.

Comment: @CGCampbell perhaps also pee-pee or poo-poo, and the ambiguity works for extra gross-out value.